# Shading between lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing, shading

I have a data set, and I am able to plot the data set fine, however, I have three lines on my graph and I want to shade between them (So two shading regions).

```
    ZNH2<-structure(list(value = c("154.102123376241", "129.342971722961", 
"59.214424508985", NA, "79.7543253228812", "56.9720749846859", 
"147.904588068996", "127.832589574989", "41.9504584377476", "30.210899339716", 
"189.915069536722", "206.470143151635", "269.431758501289", "330.519022331884", 
"80.9548026764334", "135.275345151106", "70.8898624532545", "333.065088493364", 
"245.671050594358", "217.694093154847", "202.293931253186", "320.08224840969", 
"152.675949949667", "85.6197139863922", "71.1857213343614", "222.044301846973", 
"111.437578615948", "991.558657706669", "77.5176101480006", "90.3789552959655", 
"117.223606151342", "44.9530550879222", "167.092674420099", "175.107272805158", 
"196.46944973477", "154.071757533894", "118.28502485382", "122.756078599527", 
"79.8304508785081", "226.840582406991", "119.065146684801", "170.225407520687", 
"177.651665865621", "175.597432999921", "104.179544790707", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "16.8437034171218", "21.589296969022", 
"21.5293178756595", NA, "17.1577492347234", "15.9453880616562", 
"45.8596992672078", "44.8514087972185", "24.0627701288669", "130.128455156461", 
"72.9531584398895", "34.6680166210599", "68.0830269285413", "45.5857868971278", 
"34.962220142646", "149.522794107249", "43.5106817194628", "80.1849936102008", 
"50.1407523335261", "25.7103931548188", "51.707257838463", "56.514058394911", 
"47.697772888689", "65.17156146864", "20.165819163686", "92.7341148329014", 
"62.2774860245454", "187.079350368038", "41.5562639058451", "28.8978603742495", 
"41.1724906723211", "5.77878944647918", "56.0880422383573", "68.4731748377562", 
"74.0245489658521", "44.7719649917539", "15.1070354391827", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", 
"0", "0", NA, "0", NA, "0.061935327", NA, "0.238451009", "0.006193533", 
"0", "0", "0.015483832", "0", NA, "0.390192559", "0.300386335", 
"0.105290056", "0", NA, "0.015483832", "0", "0.191999513", "0.151741551", 
"0.09290299", "0.021677364", "0", "0", "0.086709458", "0", "0", 
"0", NA, NA, NA, "0.021677364", NA, "0", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", 
NA, "0.030750948", "0.00615019", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0.018450569", "0", "0", "0", "0", NA, "0.017852517", "0", 
NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0.014648219", NA, "0", "0.017852517", 
"0.008239623", NA, "0.017852517", "0", "0.021056815", "0.005035325", 
"0.030669709", "0.027465411", "0.043486901", "0.017852517", "0.005035325", 
"0.024261113", "0", "0", "0.001831027", "0.014648219", "0", "0.017852517", 
"0.037078305", NA, NA, NA, "0.027465411", NA, "0.008239623", 
"0.046691199", "0.088347072", "0.011443921", "0.008239623", "0.033874007", 
NA, "0.037078305", "0.011443921", "0.014648219", "0", "0.024261113", 
"0.005035325", "0.005035325", "0.296626438", "0.053099794", "0.017852517", 
"0.040282603", "0.001831027", "0", "0", NA, "0.004881939", NA, 
"0.011095317", "0.032842138", "0.042162204", "0.017308694", "0.032842138", 
"0.014202006", NA, "0.00183211", "0", "0.033894034", "0.046718803", 
"0.011450687", "0.040306418", "0.037100226", "0.017863072", "0.030687841", 
"0", "0", "0.00183211", "0", "0", NA, "0.007988628", "0.091869224", 
NA, NA, NA, "0.024275457", "0.00183211", NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, 
"0", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "0.005038302", "0", "0.242296538", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0.033894034", "0.00183211", "0.005038302", 
"0.017863072", "0.030687841", "0", "0.153675746", NA, "0.020562248", 
"0.007575565", "0.008657789", "0.011904459", "0.001082224", "0.006493341", 
"0.011904459", "0.006493341", "0.018397801", "0.010822236", "0.017315577", 
"0.011904459", "0.020562248", "0.041124495", NA, NA, NA, "0.014068906", 
"0.067097861", "0.004328894", "0.006493341", "0.002164447", "0.038960048", 
"0.020562248", "0.019480024", NA, NA, "1.311886266", NA, "2.046087257", 
"2.139996686", "0.295956988", "1.343189409", "2.088773361", "2.029012815", 
"1.579385852", "1.272045902", "1.6676038", "0.130904053", "1.838348217", 
"2.003401153", "2.066007439", "2.108693543", "2.677841597", "2.071698919", 
"2.048932997", NA, NA, NA, "0.700052107", NA, "0.017074442", 
"0.073989247", NA, "1.072844083", "1.109838707", "0.093156627", 
NA, "0.069599779", NA, NA, "0.048184462", "0.103864285", "0.099581222", 
"0.098510456", "0.091015095", "0", "0.014990722", "0.18738402", 
"0.244134608", "0.301955963", "0.239851545", NA, "0.085661266", 
NA, "0.01284919", "0", NA, "0.029981443", "0.005353829", "0.67458247", 
"0.033193741", "0.032122975", NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.012553306", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", "0.028244939", "0.034521592", "0.059628204", 
NA, "0.056489878", "0.028244939", "0.062766531", NA, "0.018829959", 
NA, "0.003138327", NA, NA, "0.028244939", "0", "0.382875839", 
"0.009221717", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", 
"0", "0", "0", NA, "0", NA, NA, NA, "0.003073906", NA, "0", "0", 
NA, "0.015369529", "0", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "2", "1"), 
    `Sample type` = c("K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", 
    "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "K2SO4_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", 
    "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "H2O_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", 
    "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "Vac_18", "id.vars", 
    "id.vars"), Z = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Date2 = structure(c(17686, 17686, 17686, 
    17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 
    17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 
    17686, 17686, 17686, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17708, 
    17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17735, 17735, 
    17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17763, 17763, 17763, 
    17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 
    17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 
    17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 17686, 
    17686, 17686, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17708, 17708, 
    17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17735, 17735, 17735, 
    17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 
    17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 
    17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 
    17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 
    17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17682, 17691, 17691, 17691, 
    17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 
    17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 
    17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17691, 17698, 
    17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 
    17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 
    17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 17698, 
    17698, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 17703, 
    17703, 17703, 17703, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 17708, 
    17708, 17708, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 
    17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 
    17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17710, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 
    17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 
    17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 
    17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17718, 17726, 17726, 
    17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 
    17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 
    17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 17726, 
    17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 
    17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 17732, 
    17732, 17732, 17732, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 17735, 
    17735, 17735, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 
    17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 
    17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 
    17740, 17740, 17740, 17740, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 
    17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 
    17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 
    17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17747, 17752, 17752, 17752, 
    17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 
    17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 
    17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17752, 17759, 
    17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 
    17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 
    17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 17759, 
    17759, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 17763, 
    17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 
    17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 
    17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 17767, 
    17767, 17767, NA, NA), class = "Date")), .Names = c("value", 
"Sample type", "Z", "Date2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-493L))
```

I use the below code to make a graph:

```
 p<-ggplot(ZNH2, aes(ZNH2$Date2,ZNH2$value,color=ZNH2$`Sample type`, na.rm=T))+
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "point",lwd=6) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean,geom = "line",lwd=2) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", lwd=1.5, width = 1)
```

When attempting to add the shaded regions I am having issues because each line has variable lengths of data and no matter how I have tried to set this up I receive error messages. I've tried using geom_rect, geom_polygon, geom_ribbon, and several others. I could use help on how to set up any function capable of shading within ggplot.

The below image is the graph that I currently have. attempting to shade between Green and red, red and blue, as well as blue and x-axis all in different colors

[image: image 1: attempting to shade between Green and red, red and blue, as well as blue and x-axis all in different colors]
[image: image 2: This image shows current graphs after shading, the issue is that I get two different shades of the green due to layering. How can I tell ggplot to shade between data sets and not all the way to y=0]

Comment: Your image didn't upload correctly - can you fix it so we have a better idea of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Use `geom_ribbon` for shading areas. I would also strongly recommend doing your data manipulation before plotting, using `dplyr` or `data.table`, rather than trying to force a graphics package like `ggplot` to do your data manipulation inside `stat_summary`. `stat_summary` is great for quick little stuff, but for anything more complicated it's more straightforward to separate those two pieces of work.

Comment: the "character string" error is because you're giving the dates in as.Date() in dmy format instead of ymd (e.g. 2018-6-4).

Comment: @iod am unable to post pictures, if possible recreate using the code or follow the link. the character string fix definitely doesn't fix anything.

Comment: @Gregor, This is the only way the error bars come out. I think ggplot should be capable of taking simple means and SE? doing this before ggplot causes many issues. Note that this is not my raw data set but a well-manicured set of columns that I formed to make this graph.  How would I set up geom_ribbon to do this, I can't get this function to do anything I want in this context.

Comment: @Gregor, There are multiple measurements on each day for each sample type (maybe a couple of days where there is only one measurement, but then no error bar is put in)... Not sure what you're talking about. Did you load the above dataset?

Comment: Hmm, my mistake

Comment: The graph does average the data by day and 'sample type'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you want an area chart. This is the name of a chart that shades between a line and the axis, and by ordering the factors correctly with the highest values layered "underneath" the lowest values.

As a side-note, **never use `$` inside `aes`**, it's probably the root of a lot of your problems here. Whenever you use `$` you're forcing the entire column vector, overriding any grouping that might be going on (by facet, by x, by color...). Using unquoted column names allows `ggplot` to do it's own manipulation of sub-data frames.

```
 library(dplyr)
 agg_data = ZNH2 %>%
   mutate(Type = `Sample type`, value = as.numeric(value)) %>% 
   group_by(Date2, Type) %>%
   summarize(mean_value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
             se = sqrt(var(value, na.rm = TRUE) / sum(!is.na(value)))) %>%
   filter(Type != "id.vars") %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(Type = factor(Type),
          Type = reorder(Type, -mean_value, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot(agg_data, aes(x = Date2, y = mean_value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_area(position = 'identity', alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Type), lwd = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_value - se, ymax = mean_value + se, color = Type), lwd = 0.7, width = 1) +
  geom_point(shape = 21)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will avoid using "$" in aes. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get this code to run. The data frame agg_data has only na's in the mean_value column. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like your `value` column in the `dput` data is of class `character`. I must have converted it at some point. Code updated, and it runs fine on the `dput` data in your question.

Comment: ZNH2$value<-as.numeric(as.character(ZNH2$value)) seemed to fix this issue.

Comment: Sorry to be full of questions today. But the next graphical issue i am having is that the color scheme of the shaded areas isn't conforming to my color blind pallet in my theme settings. can i fix this or would i need to manually change the area colors seperate from lines and points?

Comment: They shading is a `fill`, whereas everything else is a `color`. You'll need to set both.

Comment: This is a colourblind palette?! I can barely tell the difference between the two top lines (green and red, right? That's, like, the most basic no-no of colour selection...)

Comment: @iod, no, this is the default ggplot palette. Kyle is saying he wants to use a colorblind palette instead.

Comment: I figured it out. @gregor understood the issue perfectly. Thanks! You hit the nail on the head!

Comment: Sorry to return to this graph but I have run into an issue here. When I use the ggplot code above the shaded regions overlap, so the red is on the bottom layer and the other two colors stack on top. The issue here is that when I have uneven datasets for these different analyses, and then only part of the blue would have red and green under it creating two different shades of blue.

Comment: *"...only part of the blue would have red and green under it creating two different shades of blue."* This sounds like a good thing, right? You can tell what's under the blue. You can play with the `alpha` level to adjust how transparent it is. Your other option is to not use transparency so you can't see through colors at all (omit the `alpha` entirely), but then you'll need to be very careful with the ordering of your factors to pick which one is plotted "on top".

Comment: However, when you look at the graph that I posted with orange blue and green as the shaded colors there are two different shades of green, because part has other shading underneath and the other portion doesnt. The objective is to shade between the data sets as we subtract them to accuire the values of the shaded reigions. but because the green is two different shades this wouldnt be a publishable graph as the reigion represents a consistent measurment.

Comment: Okay, so your options are (a) don't use transparency (omit `alpha`), maybe use a lighter shade for the `fill` so it still looks shaded. (b) Do the subtraction. Your comment mentions "as we subtract them to accuire the values of the shaded reigions". No subtraction is happening here, neither in your question nor in my answer. If you do the subtraction you could use `position = "stack"` instead of `position = "identity"`. (You'll still want the un-subtracted values for the `point` and `errorbar` layers.)

Comment: If you need help with either of those options, I'd recommend asking a new question with a suitable data set to illustrate that problem. As you mention, in the data you posted for this question (and in this answer), the problem you still need help with isn't evident.